# vb.net asp.net webforms application > c# asp.net mvc razor application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

we are looking at migrating our vb.net webforms application to c# mvc. We appreciate this may need to be done in stages but was wondering if anyone else has any experience of this architectural change.

The article below appears to show a method of getting vb.mvc and vb.webforms in the same application.

http://www.devcurry.com/2013/05/adopting-aspnet-mvc-enhancements-in.html

Since we are using a web application rather than a website we cannot mix languages i believe.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the business logic out of the VB.Net project, into a separate library, and add a reference to that library to both your old VB.Net site and the new C# MVC project.

As long as the business logic doesn't change, you can manually convert the ASP.Net application into an MVC application, by rebuilding it on the same business logic, but with Models, Views and Controllers instead of masterpages, html builders and literals.

When you are done, you can optionally convert the VB.Net business logic to C#.

Comment: This product is quite large and thus we are looking at a method of converting parts, and new functionality piece by piece. So old and new will live side by side. Unfortunately this is the only feasible way that we will be able to fit this upgrade in. as the product has an active release schedule with a major release per year and several minor feature releases.

Comment: To be honest, unless this project is an urgent matter, I would not convert it piece by piece. Instead, I would work on the new mvc project separately until it is done, then replace the whole product at once. This will prevent debugging headaches and will allow for faster development on MVC, because you will not have to worry about keeping structure to support vb web-forms. On top of that you will have more freedom on development this way, you can opt for Entity Framework for example.

Comment: the seperate project approach is not really a possibility. Despite its difficulty a stealthy upgrade piece by piece methodology is the one we are able to accomplish whilst adhering to the companies release schedule, or without employing a duplicate team of developers.

Comment: @Tim so you want to take, say, a single screen / view from the ASP.NET application, rebuild it in MVC, and let that MVC view replace the ASP.NET screen in production?